# ArrayList value is not printing in the LogCat

Tags: java, android, sqlite

DBAdapter class function:

```
public void getValues(){

        Cursor mCursor = db.query(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {
                EDGE_ID,
                SOURCE_NODE_ID,
                DESTINATION_NODE_ID,
                VALUE1}, null, null, null, null, null);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.SOURCE_NODE_ID)));
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }

        for(String d1:mArrayList) {
            System.out.println(d1);
        }
    }
```

Below is main activity class :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    db.getValues();
    db.close();
}
```

According to above code I should get an array list which contain the values of my database table of

SOURCE_NODE_ID

attribute.
and I want to print this arraylist in LogCat. But I get following error:

```
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.navigationsystem/com.navigationsystem.NavigationSystemActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.navigationsystem.DBAdapter.getValues(DBAdapter.java:117)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.navigationsystem.NavigationSystemActivity.onCreate(NavigationSystemActivity.java:53)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     ... 11 more
```

What is wrong in this code.

thanks.

Comment: What is on the line 117 in DBAdapter.java?

Comment: You are getting a `NullPointerException` in line 117 of DBAdapter.java. Check the statement on that line.

Comment: in line 117 I have: Cursor mCursor = db.query(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE2, new String[] {...

Comment: where is this line final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); is in any method? Please give complete code also

Comment: now its working.Actually I didn't open the database before db.getvalues().

Comment: Please provide the DBAdapter class as it looks in getValues db is null so we want to look where you created that........

Comment: i forgot to write db.open() and db.close().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-30 14:51:39.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at com.navigationsystem.DBAdapter.getValues(DBAdapter.java:117)
```

You have a `NullPointer` within your Code.

I think `mArrayList` is `null` within your `getValue()` method. Where did you create that List?

Maybe the `db` is also `null` within you `DBAdapter`. Have you tried debugging? Did you outputtet the variables?

Comment: now its working.Actually  
i forgot to write db.open() and db.close().